# Word: Insert shape into table cell that is in a text box

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to insert a shape into a table cell, however, Word keeps converting the shape into a picture which is not desired.

The unusual thing is I have been able to copy a shape into a table cell in another document but not this one. I tried to change the wrap to `in line with text` but did not work.

The shapes on the other document are a group of two different shapes and have `in front of text` wrap if that is of any relevance to the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: reason is table is inside a textbox but have not found a solution yet.

Comment: You are trying to put a shape inside another shape, which I do not believe is permitted. *(A textbox is a shape in recent versions of Word.)* Why are you putting a table inside a textbox?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am using textboxes for formatting purposes.

Comment: Look into using Frames and/or Tables to do the same thing. Here is my comparison of Text Boxes and Frames. http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage The page also shows how to insert a Frame. Also, you can move tables around in Word and have text flow around them.

Comment: Inserting a shape into a table inside a frame works fine. Thanks for the suggestion and website resource. I was using textboxes due to there being many graphical elements.